Getting "Resolver error: Error: Got bad result from install script" when connecting to remote through remote ssh plugin
I'm getting the error "Got bad result from install script" whenever I attempt to connect to my remote host through the vscode remote ssh plugin.
I've seen a few other answers that temporarily fix the issue (killing the vscode server on the remote instance/ deleting ~/.vscode-server) but they only work a small percentage of the time.
Here is the stack trace
EOSSH'
[14:17:26.515] "install" terminal command done
[14:17:26.516] Install terminal quit with output: 
[14:17:26.519] Resolver error: Error: Got bad result from install script
    at v.Create (/Users/chris/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/extension.js:2:501404)
    at t.tryInstall (/Users/chris/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/extension.js:2:616196)
    at async /Users/chris/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/extension.js:2:575788
    at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (/Users/chris/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/extension.js:2:579017)
    at async k (/Users/chris/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/extension.js:2:572574)
    at async t.resolve (/Users/chris/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/extension.js:2:576428)
    at async /Users/chris/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/extension.js:2:844803
[14:17:26.522] ------

My vscode is up to date, and I'm on MacOS 14.6.1 (23G93), connecting from an M3 Mac
